# How to create Play framework 2.0 debian package?

Tags: package, debian, playframework-2.0, dpkg

I would need to create a dpkg out of Play 2.0 Java project. It would run stand-alone with MongoDB (or some RDBS). It should be able to shutdown older version and ensure new version starts up cleanly.

Any advice how to create such? Any Play 2.0 related issues to take into account?

Edit: Looks like I will be using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

All these package manager installs basically run scritps. So first I would write bash scripts for uninstall, upgrade and install. You have to consider what parts can be replaced in the reinstall and how apply migrations on the database, file copy, and start stop of services. This is the hard part compared to creating a bundle. Only thing to consider for play! is stopping and starting the server when something needs to be replaced.

This might inspire you for startup shutdown scritps: https://gist.github.com/THemming/2173037